# Pros and cons of lightning view?

Tags: lightning-experience, developer

What are the pros and cons and the different between classic view and lightning view? (as a developer) .. beside the different of the UI (ofcourse it looks more cooler and user friendly)..

I dont have (yet) any experience on lighting view because all of my past project using classic view..

Comment: There is a list which you can check [Compare Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_aloha_comparison.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a developer, the only pro for Classic is that it is a mature technology, and very stable. Lightning is still constantly in flux and missing some key features, but as it matures, it will easily be better than Classic in every way. Faster load times, more responsive UI, overall less code for complicated interfaces, less duplicate code, and so on. As Tushar stated, you might want to look at the [comparison chart](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_aloha_comparison.htm&type=5), but generally speaking, as a developer, you should want to learn how to use Lightning moving forward, especially as Classic is nearing its end of life.

Comment: great, there`s so much to learn then.. Thanks!